# Regex for repeated substring with possibly truncated end

Tags: regex, string, scripting, substring, bioinformatics

I am currently working on a particular task that is based in Genetics but is mostly a regex/scripting problem. I am trying to identify (and ultimately omit) all lines of a tab-delimited file where the entry in a named subfield in a semicolon-delimited column satisfies a certain condition. Ultimately, I am looking for base-pair sequences that consist of a short sub-sequence repeated for the length of the string. Just to give an impression of the kind of thing I am talking about (since a wall of text isn't as permeable as an example), here are a couple of cases I might consider, with incidental meta-context simplified for the purposes of the illustration:

```
A    1     FOO=BLAH;BAR=BLAH;FIELD=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;  /* should match this */
B    2     FOO=BLAH;BAR=BLAH; /* not all records have this subfield; these should not be filtered out */
C    3     FOO=BLAH;BAR=BLAH;FIELD=CATCATCATCATCATCAT; /* this should also be matched */
D    4     FOO=BLAH;BAR=BLAH;FIELD=ATACGGGGGCCATCG; /* the GGGGG in the middle should not count; this line should not be matched */
E    5     FOO=BLAH;BAR=BLAH;FIELD=CTTTCTTTCTTTCTTTCTTTCTT; /* this should be matched, because the sequence is repeated throughout the string, even if it is truncated */
E    6     FOO=BLAH;BAR=BLAH;FIELD=CTTTCTTTCTTTCTTTCTTTAG; /* this should not be matched, because unlike E(5) the trailing sequence is not a truncated version of the repeating sequence */
```

I currently have a simple expression in `sed` that behaves correctly for lines A1 through D4, but doesn't get E5 right (but therefore gets E6 right):

```
sed -r '/FIELD=(.{1,4})\1{4,};/d;'
```

For the moment I am only looking for repeated sequences where the 'words' are 1-4 letters long, with at least 4 repetitions following the initial occurrence at the beginning of the string. I don't know enough regex voodoo to know how to do this, or whether this is beyond the capabilities of regex alone and would need a proper scripting language to tackle. As far as I can tell, the question boils down to, "how can I write a regex expression that allows a partial match on a back-ref only on the tail of a sequence of repetitions," but I wanted to avoid boiling down the exact details to a possibly misleading synopsis, and provide the full details so that anyone who has experience with an identical problem in another (or the same) field of study can better recognize it.

## EDIT

I came up with a solution that seems to work pretty well, which I wrote in AWK and mostly avoided using regexes for.

```
function testr(seq, maxlen, minrep)
{
    len = length(seq);
    for (i = 1; i <=maxlen; i++) {
    reps = int(len/i) - 1;
    if (reps < minrep) { return 0; }
    x = substr(seq, 1, i);
    y = substr(seq, i+1, i*reps);
    z = substr(seq, i*(reps+1)+1);
    str="";
    b=0;
    for (j=1; j < reps; j++) {
        str = str x;
        if (str != substr(y, 1, i*j)) {
            b=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (b) { continue; }
    if (x ~ z && gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]/, "", z)==0) {
        return 1;
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This function loops through the acceptable word-lengths (1 through maxlen) and tests whether the string is built out of words of that length, by capturing the first word, the concatenation of all full words, and the truncated end-word (if there is any) in separate strings; it then concatenates the first word to itself and incrementally compares it to the full-word string, breaking and continuing if it ever doesn't match; after that it tests to see whether the final word (which might be empty) matches the complete word, by using a fixed regex comparison, followed by a test to make sure that it wasn't matching on any characters with special regex meaning by seeing if there were any non-alphabetic characters in the string (this test could be replaced by seeing whether the last word is either empty or equal to the left-justified substring of the full word of its own length). Capturing the field itself is left up to the main loop of the AWK script, which is simple enough. This question is still open to all answers, so feel free to post your own approach to this.

I didn't want to overload this with test-cases initially, as that would detract from the clarity, but I am including cases to consider below, along with the matches (Y) and non-matches (N) according to this script:

```
N:AAAAAABBBBBAAA
Y:AAAAA
Y:AAAA
N:AAA
Y:BABABABABABA
Y:BABABABABAB
Y:BABABABABA
Y:BABABABA
Y:ABCABCABCABCABCABC
Y:ABCABCABCABCABCAB
Y:ABCABCABCABCABCA
N:ABCABCABCABCABCAD
N:ABCABCABCABCABCA.
Y:ABCDABCDABCDABCDABC
Y:ABCDABCDABCDABCDAB
Y:ABCDABCDABCDABCDA
N:ABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDE
N:ABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEABCD
```

Just to make testing easier, you can replace "FIELD=" with ".:" in the test, and if you get all lines with "Y:" and no lines with "N:", your approach and mine are close enough; for this case, I limited the search to words of length 1-4, with at least 3 repetitions (i.e. at least four full matches).

Comment: I wrote a tool filtering VCF with javascript: https://github.com/lindenb/jvarkit/wiki/VCFFilterJS : it would be easier to test your expression using some loops (0->length:4) rather than looking for a regex .

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex using `grep`:

```
grep -E 'FIELD=((.)(.)?(.)?(.)?)\1{4,}(\2|\3|\4|\5)*;' file
A    1     FOO=BLAH;BAR=BLAH;FIELD=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;  /* should match this */
C    3     FOO=BLAH;BAR=BLAH;FIELD=CATCATCATCATCATCAT; /* this should also be matched */
E    5     FOO=BLAH;BAR=BLAH;FIELD=CTTTCTTTCTTTCTTTCTTTCTT; /* this should be matched, because the sequence is repeated throughout the string, even if it is truncated */
```

This `sed` will also work but is slower than `grep`

```
sed -nr '/FIELD=((.)(.)?(.)?(.)?)\1{4,}(\2|\3|\4|\5)*;/p' file
```

Comment: I don't want random text after 4+ matches, I want an exact head-match of the group in question; your expression would match 'catcatcatcatcat<SHAKESPEARE'S FULL WORKS WITHOUT SEMICOLONS>;', whereas I would only want to match 'catcatcat<...>cat(c|ca)?;' but with the correct alternatives for the last item, in a fully generalized way.

Comment: Comment is difficult to understand. Can you update your question with an example to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that seems to work pretty well, which I wrote in AWK and mostly avoided using regexes for.

```
function testr(seq, maxlen, minrep)
{
    len = length(seq);
    for (i = 1; i <=maxlen; i++) {
    reps = int(len/i) - 1;
    if (reps < minrep) { return 0; }
    x = substr(seq, 1, i);
    y = substr(seq, i+1, i*reps);
    z = substr(seq, i*(reps+1)+1);
    str="";
    b=0;
    for (j=1; j < reps; j++) {
        str = str x;
        if (str != substr(y, 1, i*j)) {
            b=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (b) { continue; }
    if (x ~ z && gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]/, "", z)==0) {
        return 1;
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This function loops through the acceptable word-lengths (1 through maxlen) and tests whether the string is built out of words of that length, by capturing the first word, the concatenation of all full words, and the truncated end-word (if there is any) in separate strings; it then concatenates the first word to itself and incrementally compares it to the full-word string, breaking and continuing if it ever doesn't match; after that it tests to see whether the final word (which might be empty) matches the complete word, by using a fixed regex comparison, followed by a test to make sure that it wasn't matching on any characters with special regex meaning by seeing if there were any non-alphabetic characters in the string (this test could be replaced by seeing whether the last word is either empty or equal to the left-justified substring of the full word of its own length). Capturing the field itself is left up to the main loop of the AWK script, which is simple enough. This question is still open to all answers, so feel free to post your own approach to this.

I didn't want to overload this with test-cases initially, as that would detract from the clarity, but I am including cases to consider below, along with the matches (Y) and non-matches (N) according to this script:

```
N:AAAAAABBBBBAAA
Y:AAAAA
Y:AAAA
N:AAA
Y:BABABABABABA
Y:BABABABABAB
Y:BABABABABA
Y:BABABABA
Y:ABCABCABCABCABCABC
Y:ABCABCABCABCABCAB
Y:ABCABCABCABCABCA
N:ABCABCABCABCABCAD
N:ABCABCABCABCABCA.
Y:ABCDABCDABCDABCDABC
Y:ABCDABCDABCDABCDAB
Y:ABCDABCDABCDABCDA
N:ABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDE
N:ABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEABCD
```

Just to make testing easier, you can replace "FIELD=" with ".:" in the test, and if you get all lines with "Y:" and no lines with "N:", your approach and mine are close enough; for this case, I limited the search to words of length 1-4, with at least 3 repetitions (i.e. at least four full matches).

–  archaephyrryx